# Someone answered an on hold question

Tags: bug, answers, on-hold

This question was asked on Philosophy.SE, but if it's somehow possible to answer questions that are put on hold, that's a network wide issue.

Link: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/23976/2953

Question was put on hold 2015-05-19 14:28:44Z.
Answer was posted 2015-05-19 17:33:38Z.